# Syntax error while executing a sql request with parameters in symfony?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, parameter-passing, symfony4

I have a just simple problem I guess, I followed Symfony 4.3 documentation, and tried to do do exactly what they have done to execute a SQL request, but I get an error when passing parameters in the execute method, but I get no error while executing the same code but without passing parameters to the request.

I tried this and it worked:

```
    $conn = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection();

    $sql = '
        SELECT * FROM question_comment WHERE question=2 LIMIT 0, 3';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
```

But this does not work, I get a syntax error:

```
    $question = $request->query->get('question');
    $row = $request->query->get('row');

    $question = intval($question);
    $beggining = intval($row*3);

    $conn = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection();

    $sql = '
        SELECT * FROM question_comment WHERE question=:question LIMIT :beggining , 3';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(['question' => $question, 'beggining' => $beggining]);
    var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
```

This is the error:

> An exception occurred while executing ' SELECT * FROM question_comment
>   WHERE question= :question LIMIT :beggining , 3' with params [2, 0]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0' , 3' at
>   line 1

[Here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-with-dql-or-sql) is what I have followed, I did exactly what was there, but its not working.

I tried this solution to bind my parameters but it did not work too :

```
 $sql = '
            SELECT * FROM question_comment WHERE question=:question LIMIT :beggining , 3';
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':question', $question, \PDO::PARAM_INT); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':beginning', $beginning, \PDO::PARAM_INT); 
        $stmt->execute();
```

And I got this :

> An exception occurred while executing ' SELECT * FROM question_comment
>   WHERE question=:question LIMIT :beggining , 3' with params [2, null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: try this   $stmt->execute([':question' => $question, ':beggining' => $beggining]);

Comment: @metal it did not work :(

Comment: i believe symfony is using PDO, might want to change this to $stmt->bindParam(':question', $question, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: seems this is null $row = $request->query->get('row');, what are the columns of this table question_comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alternative way to bind parameters is using this.

```
 $stmt->bindParam(':question', $question, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
 $stmt->bindParam(':beginning', $beginning, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

or to make it sure you binded the $beginning parameter, cast it to int.

```
$stmt->bindValue(':beginning', (int)trim($beginning), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

or if you want to stick on your existing code.

```
$stmt->execute(['question' => $question, 'beggining' => (int)trim($beggining)]);
```

Comment: its because your  $request->query->get('row') is null

Comment: No, surely not that, I commented my code causing the problem and checked the $row variable with var_dump function and I get it right

Comment: I did change PARAM_STR to PARAM_INT and same things, it is weird, I am making sure that $question and $begginig are integer with intval() method but same things :(

Comment: It worked, I mispelled something above, but your bindParams method was really helpful, thank you.